# Ubuntu 20.04 lock screen stays on

Tags: 20.04, radeon, lock-screen

I have dual screens and a Radeon 5700; when the screen lock happens, auto or manual makes no difference, the screen lock comes up then blanks after a short time, then around 20s later the screen goes back to the lock screen.

I can log in and everything is fine, except I have noticed there is now some burn-in occurring. The lock screen is visible for around 30s then off for 20s, and it keeps cycling like that whilst locked.

The burn-in is minor for now, just the ghost of the clock is visible on a really dark background.

How do I make sure that the screen stays blank until there is some input. The issue still happens if I unplug my KB and mouse.